# How to fix an issue connecting reactjs with node

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to connect bet react on frontend and nodejs on the backend using proxy and this is the message it gives me:

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/v1/car from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:4001/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).

I tried all the possible ways i could think of ,do you guys have any solutions?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some code to get the desired solution. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show the package.json file snippet?

Comment: I think the solution to this is to run **node server.js** instead of **npm start**. But first you need to add _server.js_ file to access the server.